# How do I get a Hebrew keyboard layout with Caps-Shift-based Niqqud (SI 1452)?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb, i18n

In Microsoft Windows, the Hebrew keyboard layout has Hebrew characters in the basic state, English capital letters in Shift state or in Caps Lock state, but if you use Shift when Num Lock is on, you can enter Hebrew [Niqqud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) - diacritical/pronunciation signs: Shift-Num-row-8 is Qamats, Shift-Backslash is Qubuts and so on.

Now, whether you think that's a good layout or not - I'm used to it. And I want it on Linux. In the olden days of XFree86 X11R6 I remember there was a way to mess the xkb to get a Hebrew layout variant that had something similar: [SI 1452](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/si1452.html). But I don't see it mentioned in my Keyboard Layout dialog (XFCE on GNU/Linux Mint 18.2, based on Ubuntu 16.04). And Googling, I seem to only find highly outdated instructions.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The SI 1452 keyboard layout variant has been adopted as the *default* layout for Hebrew, so one should be able to type Hebrew characters without changing the layout - but not the way OP is used to.

To type Niqqud, one has to hold down the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, which is the "Third Level" modifier key, when pressing the appropriate key. Some of these keys correspond to the first letter of the character they produce, e.g. <kbd>ד</kbd> ("Daled") for an emphasis mark (which in Hebrew is a דגש, "Dagesh").

See also [this](https://www.safa-ivrit.org/alphabet/howto_win.php) more detailed explanation in Hebrew.

Comment: I could not read the Hebrew at the link, but the keyboard picture and accompanying table there were very helpful.

Comment: @PaulLynch: You could use Google Translate on that page.

Comment: Worth clarifying that SI 1452-1 and 1452-2 are distinct standards. -2 not just added niqqud but also [moved some letters](http://mikladot.com/) is NOT adopted as default — would break habits.  However it seems -2 style access to _niqqud_  with AltGr has been merged into default layout.